# How can I hide absolute numbers from the tooltip on a Pie Chart in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio pie chart showing the % of the `Record Count` metric, for various slices, but on hover, the tooltip shows the absolute number of `Record Count`. I don't want to share the absolute numbers with the customer receiving this report. How can I hide that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems not possible as of now, here is the [same question in the official support forum](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/12361146/how-can-i-disable-popups-when-hovering-over-a-chart-table?hl=en).

As stated by a user, the only possible workaround is to add a trasparent square over the chart, this would prevent the hover functionality to work.

Answer (score 1):

Define your metric used in the pie chart as a percentage by setting the Comparison Calculation field to "percent of total". When hovering the mouse, something in the format 10%(10%) will be displayed on the card. Thus, the absolute value does not appear, even if the percentage is doubled.[image]

Comment: Thanks but for `Record Count` you can only use `Auto` aggregation

Comment: How strange, this example I shared was used Record count, and here it works perfectly. Suggest that you review your answer, as the Record Cuunt does not interfere with the result I mentioned being obtained. Perhaps the problem that does not allow him to reach the result is another one.

Comment: Sorry you are quite right!!  What I meant is that the Aggregation of Record Count can only be AUT but indeed Comparison calculator can be "Percent of Total" and that solves it thanks!!